# How to fix the Discord login loop in Quart

Tags: python-3.x, flask, discord.py, quart, hypercorn

I seted up a Discord Dasboard for my Bot it runs perfactly on my computer but i tryed to run it on Heroku but, If i want to login it is going to log me in go to callback and go back to login because the discord.authorized gives False if you want to see code like i did [here](https://github.com/CodeWithSwastik/Dashboard-Tutorials/tree/main/Part%203)

Comment: The discord.authorized error is usually caused as a result of an invalid API key, head over to https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro then get yourself a new key.

Comment: @Ironstone1_ I i tryed it but i looked again in the logs now it looks like it is going to login it brings me to the authorized page after the authorize the discord.callback doesnt give any respons and thats why i got back to login do you have an I dea why the callback doesnt work?